# Xamarin Firebase Messaging Missing Dependency Exception

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to build an app with Xamarin and implement push notifications. 
I followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm#create-a-firebase-project-and-enable-firebase-cloud-messaging 
When I try to debug my app with an emulator in visual studio I get this error:

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: com.google.firebase.components.MissingDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency for component Component<[class com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging]>{1, type=0, deps=[Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.platforminfo.UserAgentPublisher, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsApi, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.firebase.heartbeatinfo.HeartBeatInfo, type=required, direct=true}, Dependency{anInterface=interface com.google.android.datatransport.TransportFactory, type=optional, direct=true}]}: class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId'

All of the packages are fully up-to-date and all dependent packages seem to be installed. I've scoured the internet for answers but haven't been able to find anything. Has anyone run into a similar issue?

Comment: Do you try to disable linking and other optimisations?

Comment: Yes, I've tried enabling and disabling multiple things in the android project options: linking, code shrinking, dex compiler, and others as recommended by other posts of people with similar problems.

Comment: Can you please have a try with earlier version? Remember to clean/rebuild your project after re-install those packages.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm facing similar problem, all dependencies are installed but still getting this exception.

Comment: @CloudArch - Oh crap, I forgot I posted this. I did end up figuring it out. It was actually what JackHua suggested, I had some incompatible versions of Xamarin Forms, Firebase Messaging, and the Azure Notification Hub.